# Passing a date to an oracle function results in not a valid month

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm trying to call an oracle function from c# the function is defined as:

```
FUNCTION MyFunction(sDate DATE, toLoc VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
```

my code looks like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "MyFunction";
cmd.CommandType= CommandType.StoredProcedure;

OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
cmd.Parameters["SDATE"].Value = DateTime.Now
cmd.Parameters["TOLOC"].Value = "ABC";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I've also tried adding the parameters manually, setting parameter type to `OracleDbType.Date`. I keep getting this exception:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException was caught
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at "MyFunction", line 102
ORA-06512: at line 1
  Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
```

Comment: Sounds like there is some implicit type conversion going on.

Comment: `line 102` implies that the parameters and function call were successful, and the error occurred in the PL/SQL in the function.  Can you post the relevant section of the function?  Like a_horse_with_no_name said, it's probably because of type conversion without an explicit format.

Comment: agreed with jonearles, this is a problem within the function, not in the call.

Answer (score 0):

is `cmd.Parameters["SDATE"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` any better?

Comment: try updating your SQL function to take a string and converting within the function using `TO_DATE (sDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss')`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the type of cmd.Parameters["SDATE"].Value is a DateTime object? Please refer to the documentation in the link. It says it is a Date object.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm

Comment: It's a date type, but Datetime.now or datetime.today makes no difference

Comment: try cmd.Parameters.Add("SDATE", DateTime.Now); instead